# List values inside for loop in python beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am doing some scraping in beautifulsoup. While scraping values from next pages I am using for loop. Everything is fine but when I make a list of the scraped values, I got only values of last page. Below is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

params = []
for page_number in range(0, 4):
    p = page_number*10
    params.append(p)
print(params)

gymname_list = []    
gymratings_list =[]
gymnumreviews_list = []
gymcat_list = []

for i in params:
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2)   AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9'}
    url= f'https://www.yelp.com.au/search?find_desc=gyms&find_loc=Berlin%2C%20Germany&start={i}'
    response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    page_soup=bs(response.content,'lxml')

    mains = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "mainAttributes__09f24__26-vh arrange-unit__09f24__3IxLD arrange-unit-fill__09f24__1v_h4 border-color--default__09f24__1eOdn"})

    for main in mains:
        try:
            gymname = main.find("a", {"class": "css-166la90"}).text
            print(gymname)
        except:
            print(None)
            
    gymname_list.append(gymname)
```

In the code above, as you can see, I am trying to scrape the first four pages but when I print "gymname" all I got is the gym name on the last i.e. the fourth page results. I want all results into my list. gymname_list. Please help

Comment: indentation for the last statement is correct ?? please check @Muhammad Rehan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last for loop, your indentation should be inside this for loop

```
for main in mains:
        try:
            gymname = main.find("a", {"class": "css-166la90"}).text
            print(gymname)
        except:
            print(None)           
        gymname_list.append(gymname)
```